# Hide a Checkbox for the current user that is logged in the App

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui, android-checkbox

I am trying to hide a `CheckBox` for the user that is logged in.
I display my data from firebase in a `RecyclerView` with `populateViewholder`. And I want to hide the `CheckBox` from the current user logged in. But I am struggling to get it right.

MainActivity:

```
public class WishItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference UsersRef, WishListRef, WishItemsRef;

static String currentUserID;

private ImageButton ibaddnewwishlistitem;

private String Key, databaseUserID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wish_items);

    Key = getIntent().getExtras().get("Key").toString();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Brukere");
    WishListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ønskelister");
    WishItemsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ønsker");

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" Ønsker");


    ibaddnewwishlistitem = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_addnewwishitem);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    WishItemList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_wishitemslist);
    WishItemList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    WishItemList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);



    ibaddnewwishlistitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SendUserToAddWishItemActivity();

        }
    });

    DisplayUserWishItems();


}

private void DisplayUserWishItems() {

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WishItemClass, WishItemViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WishItemClass, WishItemViewHolder>
                    (
                            WishItemClass.class,
                            R.layout.single_list_item,
                            WishItemViewHolder.class,
                            WishItemsRef.child(Key)


                    ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(WishItemViewHolder viewHolder, WishItemClass model, final int position) {


                    final String PostKey = getRef(position).getKey();


                    viewHolder.setWishitemname(model.getWishitemname());


                    viewHolder.setChecked(model.isChecked());



                    viewHolder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                            Intent cliconwishitem = new Intent(WishItemsActivity.this, ClickOnWishItemActivity.class);
                            cliconwishitem.putExtra("PostKey", PostKey);
                            cliconwishitem.putExtra("Key", Key);
                            startActivity(cliconwishitem);


                            return false;
                        }
                    });


                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {


                        }
                    });
                }
            };


    WishItemList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}

public static class WishItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;


    public WishItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setWishitemname(String wishitemname) {

        TextView wishitemname1 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_wishitemname);
        wishitemname1.setText(wishitemname);
    }

    public void setChecked (boolean Checked){


        CheckBox checked = (CheckBox)mView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checked.setChecked(Checked);


    }


}


private void SendUserToAddWishItemActivity() {

    Intent addwishitem = new Intent(WishItemsActivity.this, AddWishItemActivity.class);
    addwishitem.putExtra("Key", Key);
    startActivity(addwishitem);
}



private void SendUserToMainUserActivity() {

    Intent mainuseractivity = new Intent(WishItemsActivity.this, MainUserActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainuseractivity);
}

private void SendUserToAddWishListActivity() {

    Intent addwishlistactivity = new Intent(WishItemsActivity.this, AddWishItemActivity.class);
    startActivity(addwishlistactivity);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `currentUserId` from firebase auth. So you can hide/unhide checkbox based on `currentUserId`.

```
if(currentUserId != null){
    checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but where should I put this code? Inside the `populateViewholder`?

Comment: Yes, inside populateViewHolder() method

Comment: after `viewholder.setChecked(model.isChecked())` method

Comment: I have tried it. But It does not find the checked value. What can be the problem there?

Comment: The `checked` is marked red in `checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); `

Comment: that is because you initialize your checkbox in `setChecked (boolean Checked)` method.

Comment: place above in your setChecked(boolean checked) method

Comment: I have tried that now, but only this code `checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` not the `if(currentUserId != null){
    checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}` becuase i can not use `currentUserId` inside my setChecked method

Comment: Try to understand your code first, currentUserId is a global string variable, so you can user that.

Comment: But I am new to programming, so it is not that easy to understand it all. I manage to make it work without the `currentUserId`, but i guess it will hide from all the users then. So I have to try to figured it out.

Comment: Yes without `currentUserId` it will hide for all users

Comment: currentUserId will be not null for your current logged in users. And for all other users it will be null

Comment: Yes, that I understand. But I still do not know where I can put the if condition to get it working properly. Any pointers?

Comment: Just copy the code chunk provided in my answer and put it in your `setChecked(boolean checked)` method. You can use currentUserId anywhere because it has a global access

Comment: Me again, it is still marked red, but when I click on the exclamation mark to the left I can choose these options: `Make 'MainActivity.currentUserID' static` or `Make 'PostsViewHolder' not static `. Is there something wrong with my code you think?

Comment: just write `static` before `String currentUserID;`

Comment: like this `static String currentUserID;`

Comment: I have done that, but the `CheckBox` still appears/hide in all the users listitems. But something must be wrong since it does not only hide it from the currentuser.

Comment: `public void setChecked (boolean Checked)                                                        {

            CheckBox checked = (CheckBox)mView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            if(currentUserID != null){

                checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                checked.setChecked(Checked);
            }
`

Comment: Is it possible that the problems lies in my `populateViewholder`?

Comment: Did you try to log value of currentUserId

Comment: Maybe its returning null

Comment: No that I have not tried. Actually I am not sure how to do that. As I told you, I am new to Android Studio.

Comment: Use `Log.d("currentUserid",currentUserID);` before if statement and show your logcat

Comment: It is not returning null: `2019-09-14 13:34:30.485 6246-6246/com.example.server.socialnetwork D/currentUserid: runy2AkmR4PMj6zETlbDEkP0Drj2`

Comment: The id is the right current user. I use the same setVisibility method in another Activity with Buttons, and this works. Strange that this does not work.

Comment: I think the problem is with your RecyclerView

Comment: call `firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` right after `WishItemList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);`

Comment: Hi, tried that aswell.. Nothing has changed. Can it be the Firebase Database?